# Can you avoid for loops with solrj?

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, solr, solrj

I was curious if there was a way to avoid using loops when using SolrJ.

For example.  If I were to use straight SQL, using an appropriate java library, I could return a Query result and caste it as a List and pass it on up to my view (in a webapp).

SolrJ (SolrQuery and QueryResponse) have no way of returning succinct lists it seems.  This would imply I have to create an iterator to go through each return doc and get the value I want which isn't ideal.

Is there something I am missing here, is there away to avoid these seemingly useless loops?

Comment: even if you have a list, you have to iterate over it eventually, right? what exactly is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SOLRJ wiki give an example that does what you want:

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#Reading_Data_from_Solr

Basically:

```
QueryResponse rsp = server.query( query );
SolrDocumentList docs = rsp.getResults();
List<Item> beans = rsp.getBeans(Item.class);
```

EDIT:

Based on your comments below, it appears what you want is a non-looping transform of the SOLR response (e.g. a map function in a functional language). Google's guava library provides something like this. My example below assumes that your SOLR response has a "name" field that you want to return a list of:

```
QueryResponse rsp = server.query(query);
SolrDocumentList docs = rsp.getResults();

List<String> names = Lists.transform(docs, new Function<String,SolrDocument>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(SolrDocument d) {
        return (String)d.get("name");
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, java does not support this style of programming very well, so the functional approach ends up being more verbose (and probably less clear) than a simple loop:

```
QueryResponse rsp = server.query(query);
SolrDocumentList docs = rs.getResults();
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
for (SolrDocument d : docs) names.add(d.get("name"));
```

Comment: Not exactly (at least as I understand it).  What that allows you to do is define a class that represents the type of Doc returned.  Lets say you have a an index that has id's and names.  If I query the name field, I want nothing but a flat list of ids returned matching my query on the name field.

Comment: if you don't want to convert it to a java bean then just use the SolrDocumentList, which derives from ArrayList: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/common/SolrDocumentList.html

Comment: This still doesn't entirely help, but I will give you credit.  I need it in a List of strings, not array list.  Its requiring an additional transformation in order to get it to a usable form is my point.